# Customization of citation and bibliography styles with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, bibliographystyle

I am trying to change the citation style in the text so that if it is an author number equal to 2 that the "and" is put between their names (eg: Tempkin **and** Pyzhev, 1940) (not the semicolon (;) as in this case).

Also, I would like in the bibliography that the author names appear in lowercase with the initials in uppercase (eg: **Tempkin, M *and* Pyzhev, V**, 1940. Heavy metals removal and isotherms study.Acta Physiochim USSR. Vol. 12, pp. . 217–22.).

Here is my short code (example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=iso-authoryear,
maxcitenames=2,
sorting=nty,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{BiblioFile.bib}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

 Example of my citation \parencite{tempkin1940}.

 \printbibliography
 \end{document}
```

here is my BiblioFile.bib :

```
@article{tempkin1940,
title={Heavy metals removal and isotherms study},
author={Tempkin, M and Pyzhev, V},
journal={Acta Physiochim URSS},
volume={12},
pages={217--22},
year={1940}
}
```

[image: screenshot of the current rendering]

Answer (score 1):

The delimiter between names is called `finalnamedelim` between the second-to-last and last name and `multinamedelim` otherwise.

For the name format `biblatex-iso` uses the command `\familynameformat` to format names in all caps. If we redefine this macro we can suppress the caps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=iso-authoryear,
  maxcitenames=2,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\renewcommand{\familynameformat}[1]{#1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998)//Sigfridsson, Emma; Ryde, Ulf, 1998. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry. Vol. 19, no. 4, pp. 377–395. Available from doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

It wasn't clear to me from the question whether you wanted the "and" only in citations or also in the bibliography. If you also want it in the bibliography just remove the two lines

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
```

in the code above.

Comment: Big thanks, I will go through this solution. Next, I will come back to you.